# Command not found for react-native and create-react-app(Mac OS)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, path, react-native

I think I've broken my node/react-native/react PATHs/installation/links and since yesterday I'm trying to figure out what to do.

The errors are:

```
zsh: command not found: create-react-app
zsh: command not found: react-native
```

In my `which node`:

```
/usr/local/bin/node
```

My `npm get prefix`:

```
/Users/username/.npm-packages
```

My PATH is:

> /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin:/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/bin:/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/username/.npm-packages:/usr/local/bin/node:/Users/username/.rvm/bin

**EDIT:**

My workaround was uninstalling all the NODE.JS installation

**The following is the best way to completely uninstall node + npm:**

1. go to /usr/local/lib and delete any node and node_modules
2. go to /usr/local/include and delete any node and node_modules directory
3. if you installed with brew install node, then run brew uninstall node in your terminal
4. check your Home directory for any local or lib or include folders, and delete any node or node_modules from there
5. go to /usr/local/bin and delete any node executable

**You may need to do the additional instructions as well:**

1. sudo rm /usr/local/bin/npm
2. sudo rm /usr/local/share/man/man1/node.1
3. sudo rm /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d
4. sudo rm -rf ~/.npm
5. sudo rm -rf ~/.node-gyp
6. sudo rm /opt/local/bin/node
7. sudo rm /opt/local/include/node
8. sudo rm -rf /opt/local/lib/node_modules
9. sudo rm -rf /usr/local/include/node/

Comment: Have you tried running `npm install -g react-native-cli` again ?

Comment: Yes, but is not working yet: /Users/username/.npm-packages/bin/react-native -> /Users/username/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js
/Users/username/.npm-packages/lib
└── react-native-cli@1.0.0

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**
npm -g install react-native
OR
npm i -g react-native-cli

**for zsh error:**
npm install -g react-native-cli

Answer (score 0):

Use `npx` to solve the error "create-react-app: command not found".

Example:

For **React JS**: `npx create-react-app my-app`

For **React Native**: `npx react-native@latest init AwesomeProject`

or install the package globally by running `npm install -g create-react-app` to be able to use the command **without the npx prefix**.

The fastest way to solve the error is to use the `npx` command.